# How to convert it into CNF(Conjunctive normal form )

Tags: conjunctive-normal-form

i faced a expression which is below

```
A ∨ (B ∧ C) ∨ (D ∧ E ∧ ￢ (A ∨ B))
```

how to Convert into CNF(Conjunctive normal form)?

Comment: this is not a coding question.

Comment: What have you tried.  Where are you stuck?  Also are you after an equivalent formula(potential expontential blowup) or an equisatisfiable formula(polynomial transformation).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more a computer science or math question than a programming one.

Comment: Question possible belongs in http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want an equivalent formula you have to use transformations that preserves logical equivalence.

Here is a potential first step;

```
A ∨ (B ∧ C) ∨ (D ∧ E ∧ ￢(A ∨ B))
((A ∨ B) ∧ (A ∨ C)) ∨ (D ∧ E ∧ ￢A ∧ ￢B)
```

Taking distribution laws for A ∨ (B ∧ C) and applying DeMorgan to ￢(A ∨ B)